# "They told me that" which one is the direct and indirect object?

Tags: english, grammar

In the sentence "They told me that" or "They told me so"
OR even much better sentence from one of the provisional answer
"She taught me Spanish"

- Which one is the direct object? (My guess is "that" and "so" and "Spanish")
- Which one is the indirect object? (My guess is "me")

I hope to get some confirmation and this is really language agnostic, I mean to talk about the semantic underlying in the text. Thank you.

Comment: Your guess is correct. The addressee usually corresponds to the indirect object whereas the patient is expressed by the direct object.

Comment: First, **They told me it* is ungrammatical. The Dative Alternation does not apply with a pronoun as the direct object. _They told me the answer_ is OK, and so is _They told the answer to me_ and _They told it to me_. Second, what's the direct object and what's the indirect object depends on what theory you're following. In Relational Grammar, for instance, Dative changes the status of an indirect object to direct object, which can then be passivized. So the ones without _to_ don't have indirect objects, though they still have Goal and Trajector NPs, while the ones with a _to_-phrase do.

Comment: @johnlawlerinexile Changed "They told me it" to other sentence as you suggested. The question remains the same.

Comment: Approximately synonymous verbs in different languages (or even in the same language) can take different argument patterns, so I'm not sure if you can get an answer that is completely language agnostic.

Comment: @sumelic Why not, different argument patterns simply mean different grammar and syntactic rules, the conceptual meaning and idea are the same.

Comment: What I mean is things like the differences between "tell sbody" "tell sbody sthing" "tell sthing to sbody" vs. "say sthing" "say sthing to sbody";  the verbs "say" and "tell" work differently in terms of grammar. Usually, terms like "direct object" and "indirect object" are taken to only refer to grammar and syntax rules; if you want semantic roles, there's different terminology usually used for that, like "agent" "patient" or "theme". (see more at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thematic_relation)

Comment: @sumelic Thanks for the wiki page, but it is too fine-grained for my need. The vast majority of them falls into simply "prepositional object"

Answer (score 1):

As Atamiri points out, *it* is the direct object in the first example and *me* is the indirect object in the second example. The traditional explanation is that the direct object is acted upon directly, and the indirect object is affected by the action more or less indirectly. But be aware that these traditional explanations do not always work. There are instances where it is difficult to view the one or the other object as indirect or direct, e.g.  *She taught him Spanish* -- in this case, it is difficult to view *him* as "indirect", since the the "him" is being directly influenced by the teaching.

Comment: But `him` is indeed indirect object and Spanish direct object, correct?

Comment: I'm not sure about Spanish, since I don't know Spanish. But in languages that have case such as German, the notions of direct and indirect object are associated closely with case (accusative vs. dative). Accusative typically marks the direct object, and dative the indirect object. Some languages mark indirect objects with a preposition, such as with "to" in English: "I gave it to him". My guess is that Spanish also prefers to use a preposition to mark indirect objects. Direct objects are probably not marked with a preposition in Spanish. But I'm just guessing.

Comment: @InstructedA Is it grammatical to say "She taught Spanish to him?" If it is well-formed, then I'd say that "him" is indirect object. The lexical mapping of "to teach" varies greatly across languages. In Spanish the person is in the dative (le enseñé francés a ella). The same in Bavarian ("wir müssen den Kindern mehr Deutsch lernen (sic!)"), though what Stoiber wanted to say in standard German would be a double accusative construction: "die Kinder Deutsch lehren". In Russian the mapping is the other way around: я научил его чувству юмора (I taught him-ACC sense-DAT of humor). It's quite a mess.

Comment: @Atamiri I think this means that human language's grammars are still not rigorous enough that they don't provide syntactic marker to distinguish the difference. So again taking all the syntactic comfort away, I think we have to rely on semantic to realize that the objects are things other than subject and predicate. There are three types: direct object, indirect object, prepositional object. Indirect object receives direct object somehow and requires the presence of direct object. Hopefully, this cleans up the mess. If you can come up with an example that this can't clean up, please write here

Comment: @InstructedA The notion of object isn't semantic. There's a mismatch between syntax and semantics. In many IE languages for a NP to function as a direct object is for it to be able to serve as the subject of the passive form of the sentence. Obviously this criterion doesn't work for English, which is the reason why some speak of primary and secondary objects (which in turn doesn't make sense in many other languages).

Comment: @Atamiri actually, that passive voice criteria works for direct object, but it also works for indirect object and thus cannot be used to distinguish direct and indirect which is what we are doing here. Still have to rely on the semantic of which one receives the other to figure out.

Comment: @InstructedA It only works for English (and partially a few languages like ancient greek). Look at Latin or Russian or German. In English it's the primary object what can be passivized. Semantics isn't involved in either case.

Comment: @Atamiri My point is that using semantic we can distinguish indirect and direct object for all languages. Please give an example which you think makes this assertion not true.

Comment: @InstructedA Your point is wrong. The difference is BY DEFINITION not semantic. Semantics in concerned with thematic roles and I think this is what you mean. The examples are given above ("to teach" in different languages).

Comment: @Atamiri Ok, so I will rephrase my wording. My point is that **using meaning we can still distinguish indirect object and direct object**. In the example of `teach`, without any care of which language it is, we can still label direct object and indirect object using the conceptual meaning (this conceptual meaning is what I call **semantics**)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22081/discussion-between-atamiri-and-instructeda).

Answer (score 1):

Since English has no way to mark the accusative case explicitly, the only way to tell the direct object is to find an object without a preposition before it. In your sentence neither object has a preposition, so there is no way you can deny that *both* objects are direct, at least formally, judging by their form and the syntax of the whole sentence. Because of this, English is a language that can have two direct objects of a verb, and that can easily be proved: *She taught him Spanish* has 2 direct objects, if you remove one of them you can easily see that:

> She taught *him*. - "him" is the direct object.
>
> She taught *Spanish*. - "Spanish" is the direct object.

If you abstragate from the formal grammar and look at the meaning of the words and at the situation described in the sentence, it is easy to find out what the action is directed at and who it is intended for, but anyway this difference *is not expressed* in the English sentence. The order in which the objects are put after the verb doesn't tell about their nature, if a verb has two direct objects we can easily transform the sentence so that to make each of the objects indirect:

> She taught Spanish *to him*. - "to him" is the indirect object.
>
> She taught him *about Spanish*. - "about Spanish" is the indirect object.

That is why the very idea of a distinction between the direct vs. indirect object becomes vanishingly vague when we speak about English.

Comment: Thank you for the elaborated answer. However, I believe that your last sentence `She taught him about Spanish` does not have Spanish as indirect object. Spanish is simply a prepositional object anchored on the preposition `about`. In similar sentence "They talked with me about him" does not have any indirect object. Both `me` and `him` are simply prepositional objects in my view.

Comment: @InstructedA - It's all about terminology, if you call "about Spanish" a prepositional object, why not call "to him" a prepositional object too? If you look at the sentence really wide, objects are everything which is not the subject and not the predicate. "I went to London" - "to London" can well be looked at as an indirect (or call it prepositional) object. Again, I tell you, languages with the morphology reduced like in English give you a great room for arguing about the kinds of objects which are all the same not marked in any way.

Comment: In English it seems better to speak of primary and secondary objects.

Comment: @YellowSky I was thinking in the line that if there is an indirect object, there should also be a direct object as well.

Comment: @InstructedA - All I wrote was intended to show you how vague the difference between the kinds of objects is in English.

Answer (score 0):

The direct object is the noun phrase immediately after the verb.  That's the one that can be passivized (usually).

> They told *me* that. (I was told that.)
>   They told *me* so. (?I was told so.)
>   She taught *me* Spanish. (I was taught Spanish.)

Some people also allow omission of the "to" of an indirect object in passives (which is confusing):

> They told *that* to me. (That was told (to) me.)
>   She taught *Spanish* to me. (Spanish was taught (to) me.)

The indirect object is the noun phrase after "to".  I am partial to the Relational Grammar account which derives the double object construction by promoting an indirect object to a direct object (and demoting the former direct object to Chomeur).

Comment: This seems counter to the consensus I have got that `me` in your examples are not direct objects, but indirect

Comment: @InstructedA, see my note (and Lawler's earlier comment) about the Relational Grammar theory, according to which the "me" in "They told me that" is a direct object which was converted from an original indirect object.  "They told that[d.o] to me[i.o.]" ==> "They told me[d.o.] that[no grammatical relation]"

Comment: Ok, then I will have to have my own grammar theory then. In my theory, the `me` is indirect object and the `that` is direct object. That makes thing much better than having a no grammatical relation on `that`.

Comment: Greg is right. "Direct object" and "indirect object" are not defined by meaning, but by their syntax. The "Dative Alternation" describes the difference in structure between the synonymous _They told me that_ and _They told that to me_. If you just mean "receiver" (as opposed to "trajector"), then they're the same -- _me_ is the receiver and _that_ the trajector in both cases. But "object" is a syntactic relation, not a semantic one. You can't define "object" by what it means -- only by how it behaves in a sentence. Passive can apply to direct objects only, for instance.

Comment: @johnlawlerinexile  You can have passive for indirect object. Ex: `I was given a book by them` from `They gave a book to me`.

Comment: @InstructedA: Sorry, no. Passive does not delete prepositions, and **I was given a book to by them* is ungrammatical. You're missing a step. _I was given a book by them_ via Passive, from _They gave me a book_ via Dative, from _They gave a book to me_. Dative deletes the preposition and promotes the IO to DO, Passive promotes the DO to Su. Both are optional.

Comment: @johnlawlerinexile I don't understand you, you said Passive can only apply to direct object only, and I gave you an example where indirect object becomes Passive and you still say no, and said that there is an extra step where indirect object is promoted to direct object. It doesn't matter if there is an extra step of promotion or not. I think if you give me another indirect object in another sentence I can also turn it into passive subject.

Comment: In all cases, I don't think direct object and indirect object are defined by grammar. I believe they are defined by meaning, but now I will truncate both of them to just object in my theory to avoid any problem as this is a problematic debate of syntax and semantic

Comment: Obviously they are defined any way you want to define them. That's one reason why many syntactians don't use the terms except where the distinction is obvious. They're either imprecise, as you are using them, or precise only in terms of one particular formal theory of grammatical relation, like the one Greg and I are using, which is called "Relational Grammar", "Arc-Pair Grammar", and several other names. If you want to define them by meaning, the semantic terms are "Source" (subject), "Trajector" (direct object), and "Goal" (indirect object). Generally the goal NP is human.

Comment: By the way, @InstructedA, if you're really interested in the semantics behind all this stuff, then you want to read Fillmore on [Deixis](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Deixis.html) and on the [Trajectory frame](http://www.google.com/search?q=fillmore+trajectory+goal+berkeley+edu+motion+ditransitive+verb). A fair sampling of the results of his work can be seen [here, at a syntaxfest in his honor](http://linguistics.berkeley.edu/~fillmorefest/summaries.html)